# Getting 'Bad request, missing form' error when sending requests to Express app deployed on Netlify

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, netlify

Using Netlify CLI i typed `netlify deploy --prod` in my `express app` and i get:

```
✔ Finished uploading blobs to deploy store
✔ No cached functions were found
✔ Finished hashing
✔ CDN requesting 0 files
✔ Finished uploading 0 assets
✔ Deploy is live!

Build logs:        https://app.netlify.com/abcxyz
Function logs:     https://app.netlify.com/abcxyz/functions
Unique deploy URL: https://app.netlify.com/abcxyzp
Website URL:       https://app.netlify.com/abcxyz
```

In production i sent for example:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/token
```

so i tried in POSTMAN:

```
https://app.netlify.com/abcxyz/api/v1/token
```

but it didnt work. I get:

```
Bad request, missing form
```

My netlify.toml

```
[functions]
  external_node_modules = ["express"]
  node_bundler = "esbuild"
[[redirects]]
  force = true
  from = "/api/*"
  status = 200
  to = "/.netlify/functions/api/:splat"
```

and api.ts copied from netlify docs:

```
import express, { Router } from 'express';
import serverless from 'serverless-http';

const api = express();

const router = Router();
router.get('/hello', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

api.use('/api/', router);

export const handler = serverless(api);
```

How to send any request to deployed server on netlify that actually works?